# Subordinate clauses in sentences

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, clauses

I have a question about using subordinate clauses. Here are the following examples:

1. This book is about how to control your emotions in difficult situations;
2. How they love each other is felt even through photos.

And I want to ask:

1. Is such use of sub.clauses grammatically correct? I mean, subordinate clauses equal nouns in my examples, is it possible and normal in English?
2. What about punctuation in such cases as mine?

Comment: The clause *how to control your emotions in difficult situations* in 1) is a noun clause acting as the *object* of the preposition *about.* Some might call it a *complement.* In 2) the clause _How they love each other_ is a noun clause acting as the *subject* of the sentence.

Comment: Thanks . Then it’s okay to say this way... But what about punctuation?

Comment: @user405662 Not quite:"How to control your emotions in difficult situations" is an interrogative infinitival clause (embedded question) functioning as complement of the prep "about". I would avoid the term 'noun clause' -- it's misleading. The classification of subordinate clauses is based on their internal form or the category of their VP rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Answer (score -1):

Your use of the subordinate constructions is correct in both phrases.

Strictly speaking, only "*How they love each other*" in the second sentence is a "subordinate clause" in the sense of being a subordinated proposition having a conjugated verb.
It works as the subject of the second sentence.

Within the clause:

- "*They*" is the subject
- "*How ... they love each other*" is the predicate

By contrast, "*how to control your emotion in difficult situations*" is a subordinate, substantive construction, but it is not a "clause" as it has no conjugated verb, and it has no identifiable subject or predicate.

It works as the "term" part of a "circumstantial complement" that indicates what the book is about (subject/theme/reference), subordinated to the main sentence via de preposition "about".

In relation to your question about subordinate clauses (or constructions)  being nominal (substantive)  in nature, or equivalent to nouns, the answer is yes. That is a perfectly normal feature of the language.

However, notice that only the second of your clauses, "*How they love each other*" is purely nominal/substantive, as it is equivalent to a subject.

Your full second subordinate construction is  *"**about** how to control your emotions in difficult situations"*, and that is not exactly nominal, although the term part of it, "*how to control your emotions in difficult situation*", is.

**Punctuation**

One of the function of puctuation (specifically, commas) is to denote that the expected word order of a sentence has been changed somehow.

Compare:

*"Murder", she wrote.*

*She wrote "murder".*

In principle, both your sentences respect the overall expected order of the "parts of a sentence" in English: Subject - Verb - Object/predicative.

So neither commas nor other punctuation are necessary.